# Vim easy-motion after jump centre page using zz

Tags: vim

I want to be able to use easy motion to jump to a certain character then centre the page on the cursor. Hitting `zz` directly after a jump is the exact functionality i would like.

I am using the vim plugin easy-motion. I have the following mappings

```
map  <Leader>s <Plug>(easymotion-bd-f)
nmap <Leader>s <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f)
```

I want to add another like

```
map  <Leader>sz <Plug>(easymotion-bd-f) zz
nmap <Leader>sz <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f) zz
```

To centre the page after jump. Unfortunately this doesn't work and takes in the `zz` as target Input.

So how do i wait for user input then run the command `zz`?
Thank you!